# 2d matrix convolution using 1d arrays in c

Tags: c, matrix

I have to perform a 2d matrix convolution but I have used 1d arrays to store the matrices. These 1d arrays are of size `NumRows * NumCols` and hold the values of the matrices. 
I have written the following code to perform 2d convolution but I get wrong results. Can someone help me with what's wrong?

```
mat_A is of size NumRows_first * NumCols_first.
mat_B is of size NumRows_second * NumCols_second.
mat_C is the output array of size (NumRows_first + NumRows_second - 1) * (NumCols_first + NumCols_second - 1)
```

And the code that I have written is:

```
int c_x = NumRows_second / 2;
int c_y = NumCols_second / 2;
int ii = 0;
int jj = 0;
for(i=0; i<(NumRows_first + NumRows_second - 1) * (NumCols_second + NumCols_first - 1); i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<(NumRows_first + NumRows_second - 1) * (NumCols_second + NumCols_first - 1); j++)
    {
        for(int m=0; m<NumRows_second - 1; m++)
        {
            for(int k=0; k<NumCols_second - 1; k++)
            {
                ii = i + (m - c_x);
                jj = j + (k - c_y);
                if(ii >= 0 && ii < NumRows_first && jj>=0 && jj<NumCols_first)
                    mat_C[i] += mat_A[ii*jj] * mat_B[m*k];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The arrays are all of type `double`

Comment: I've done convolutions, but a quick Google search shows [Examples of 2D Convolution](http://www.songho.ca/dsp/convolution/convolution2d_example.html), [S06 Convolution](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs1114/2013sp/sections/S06_convolution.pdf), and Wikipedia on [Kernel (image processing)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing)).  All of these seem to imply that you have an image (largish) and a kernel (smallish), and that you apply the kernel to the image and generate a result that is as big as the image — clipping or scaling to truncate or expand are not convolution.

Comment: It looks as though your output is bigger than the inputs; this isn't what the links above think happens with convolution.  You don't show code zeroing the output matrix; I assume you did that before the code shown was used.  It would be sensible to progress in steps.  Make sure you can print the image and kernel matrices, for example, and that you get the right results.  Also make sure you can apply the kernel to the elements of the image — paying special attention to the edge and corner cases.  Is the kernel constrained to an odd number of cells (3x3, 5x5 and similar in the links; 3x7 too?)?

Comment: You have chosen very unfortunate variable names and it is not clear which are indices, which are coordinates, or which of either applies to what source matrix.  It is not surprising that you have a few lines of broken code and don't know how to fix it.  For me, a very quick glance at the operation on `mat_C` suggests that you're indexing wrong.  For row-major arrangement, you would normally have something that looks like `mat_A[ay * awidth + ax]` where `ax` and `ay` are the (x,y) coordinates.  Or you would arrange the convolution in scanlines.  You appear to do neither of these.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can duplicate the problem and help you to debug it.

Comment: Hmm, looking closer, I think you intended something closer to `mat_C[i] += mat_A[ii * NumCols_first + jj] * mat_B[m * NumCols_second + k]`, but of course the `ii` and `jj` calculations themselves look whack, given the outer `i` and `j` loops.  And it's strange that `mat_C` should have such huge dimensions...  unless I've been doing convolutions wrong for the last 20 years.